# Redireccionar la mismo Servlet

Tags: java, formularios, jsp, post, servlets

Qué tal? Estoy desarrollando un sistema para la tesis final de la Universidad y me he trabado hace un par de días con el siguiente problema. Resulta que en una página JSP tengo un formulario con el cual envío datos por una petición POST. Luego de mandar los dato por post quiero hacer una redirección al mismo servlet para que me cargue la misma página pero no sé como hacerlo. He intentado hacer con un request dispatchet pero me tira un error 500 diciendo que se ha excedido máximo de numero de veces que que se puede ejecutar un request dispatcher. Luego intento con un send redirect pero me tira un un error 500 null. Alguien me podría dar una mano?

Este es el código de metodo post del servlet "servAbrirFix"

```
        Gestor g = new Gestor();
        
        int idFix = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtIdFix"));
        String respuesta = request.getParameter("txtRespuesta");
        
        g.insertarResponse(idFix, respuesta);
        
        response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/servAbrirFix");
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿En qué línea te lanza el NullPointerException?

Comment: En esta línea:
response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/servAbrirFix");

Comment: El problema es que el Servlet no va a cargar la pagína solo devuelve desde el servidor la respuesta al cliente. Ahora, si puedes hacer un redirect al mismo servlet pero tienes que poner algun indicador (un parametro) que le indique que es la entrada de recarga  y debe responderse al cliente de la petición, de lo contrario, entras en un loop y el cliente se queda en espera. Ahora, no sé para que quieres hacerte una  redirección si puedes  refrescar los datos y enviar la respuesta. Lo que no veo en su Servlet es el response.

Comment: Te  manda NullPointer porque el redirect   no le manda el request y  ressponse.  que recibe el servlet.  Debes tener  presente que un Servlet recibe un requerimiento (Request) lo procesa y devuelve la respuesta (Response). No es una pagina  que pueda recargarse.  Deberías explicar un poco más la idea de  que quieres devolver a la pagina que originó el requerimiento, de lo contrario, ya te respondí.

Comment: Realmente  el Null Exception deben ser por lo datos  del Post que recibe porque el redirect regresa al navegador cliente y vuelve a llamar al servlet pero esta vez sin datos post porque el redirect no le envia nada.  La logica de recarga debe estar en el  JSP

Comment: Me explico mejor. En la pagina JSP quiero hacer los siguiente: con un formulario quiero generar un comentario y mandarlo por post a la base de datos, y en la misma página mostrar ese comentario que ingresé. Entonces por eso se me ocurre hacer un redirect al mismo servlet, para que me pueda cargar de nuevo la misma página con los comentarios generados. Me expliqué mejor?

Comment: Igual la idea que tienes es la del POST-REDIRECT-GET. O quizás quieras hacer un *forward* en vez de un redirect.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios! Pude hacerlo andar! :)